# Chrome driver issue Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the Chrome Version 110.0.5481.77 and Selenium version 4.8.1 I am having this error while running the script. It keeps crashing my driver and does not load the website.

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-3V2BQKF', ip: '10.0.0.8'
```

I have used most solution that I found on here before posting this question.

-Set the headless true.
-Killed all the Chromedriver Running Prior to the Script.
-Updated Selenium version to latest.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: include the chromedriver version in your post.  (It would also help to include webdriver intialization code and maybe some details on the machine the webdriver is running on.)

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: Same  version of chrome driver i am using

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when updating to 110. I solved it by changing `--headless` to `--headless=new`. Not sure if it helps you but it can help others.

Comment: Already tried that. does not work for me.

Comment: I dont know that is the issue still may be while building it creates the issue. I Tried to build with build.gridle using cmd command line. It does work for me. but when i run it from class it still does not work for me.